# Why are my links not followed in the mobile version of my page?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, twitter-bootstrap

At this site:

http://htmlstream.com/unify/

All the links work find on mobile devices e.g.

```
Pages -> About Us
```

Here

http://ec2-54-234-211-107.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

Which is basically an identical site (I just unzipped the purchased template) the same link doesn't appear to work. The code is effectively identical what's going wrong? Both work fine in a desktop browser.

Comment: What links don't work? I can get to the about page on both sites...

Comment: On mobile? e.g. android/iOS? For me none of the links work on the ec2 site

Comment: using Electric Mobile Studio iPad/iPhone emulator they work.

Comment: Hmmm not working for me on actual android/iPhone

Comment: you're right, SGS4 (actual phone) does break. You can get the drop-down to display, but then re-hides as you're about to click the link. My assumption is the nav container (primary menu) overlays the sub-items.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your css file:

```
.dropdown-backdrop {
  position: static;
}
```

Comment: Please explain why this will fix his problem.